# The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I am using Full Text Search with LINQ in my application and as this is not supported by LINQ I use a table-valued function workaround. The function is created on SQL Server 2008.

Surprisingly, I get error “The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid” when I search for a simply text e.g. “manager”

I used SQL Server Profiler and found out that LINQ generated the parameter as nvarchar(4000) instead of nvarchar(250) which is in my function.

The biggest surprise came when I changed my SQL Server function so it accepts parameter as nvarchar(4000) instead of nvarchar(250) and the problem is solved.

I was also playing to change the parameter to nvarchar(2000) and less but this also didn’t work.

Does anybody know  why this behaves this way?

**Updated on 18th November 2013** - **Good news and bad news**

Good news - I am now using Entity Framework 6 for this particular example and it is not anymore needed to use **nvarchar(4000)**

Bad news - You have to use instead **nvarchar(max)** :-(

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you have the database table structure cached when designing dbml. You can change it to nvarchar(max) altogether and remap it in your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an expanation see the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/1a46d676-32f0-44a4-b39f-61a17bccb8e3/.

Comment: There's a bug report for this at [https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/585759/lint-to-sql-parameter-resized](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/585759/lint-to-sql-parameter-resized)

Comment: In case anyone finds this (like I just did), the "simple" solution is to make your function parameter "VarChar(8000)" and it works.  Looks like the bug is still in place.  Even LinqPad said that my param from L2S was VarChar(1000), but I was still getting errors.

Comment: This appears to be related to the .NET version you are using. I upgraded the project to .NET 4 and got this issue. I downgraded it back to .NET 3.5 and the issue was gone, even though I keep using VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to force JAVA to call my Table-Value-Function with matching datatype as below

```
query.setParameter(0, variable, new **StringNVarcharType**()  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the size of the varchar (or nvarchar) variables are the same in your sql function and where they are declared.

In my case I had a function that declared the variable as nvarchar(100) but the stored procedure that called the function declared the variable passed in as nvarchar(200). Changing the function to be the same as the stored procedure variable fixed this.

Code below shows the non-working case with the inconsistently sized nvarchars.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_FullTextSearch](@searchExpression nvarchar(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN
   SELECT *
   FROM Company c
   WHERE contains(c.Name, @searchExpression)
GO

DECLARE @searchExpression nvarchar(200) = '"ltd"'
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_FullTextSearch](@searchExpression)
```

Comment: The problem is specific to Linq2Sql. You cannot solve it this way.

Comment: While this may not have been the answer that the original question posted was looking for, it saved me quite a bit of head scratching, so thanks for that.